# The use of "at the beginning " without "of something"

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use "at the beginning/at the end" without "of something" in a conversation that the listener knows exactly what I'm talking about?

For example: If a student asks me to go for a  drink, should I say "at the end" or "in the end" instead of "at the end of the session"?

Comment: This would only work if the "of something" was already understood by both parties.

Answer (score 1):

"In the end" is synonymous to finally and is often used without a trailing phrase.

"At the end" however, is usually followed by "of" (if not written, then at least implied). Using it just by itself seems incorrect. 
As @Davo correctly pointed out in his comment above, **if "of something" is already understood by both parties, then we may skip writing it explicitly after "at the end"**. That been said, even in this case, we are not using "at the end" just by itself.

[It would be great if someone could elaborate on this more technically]

You may find this [link](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/in-the-end-at-the-end) helpful.

Comment: I watched a movie, and stayed for the credits at the end.

Comment: @Barmar in this example, "of something" is already understood by the listener (and implied by the speaker). Please see Davo's comment above.

Comment: That's the point -- it isn't incorrect to use it by itself when the reference is understood. Isn't that essentially what the question asks -- are there times when you can leave it out, and what are those times?

Comment: You are right. I've highlighted this point in the answer. Thanks!